# Mount USB HD connected to router and shared via samba - from shell/fstab

Tags: linux, mount, samba

I'm trying to mount a USB HD connected to my router from a shell on a Raspbian server, later on via `/etc/fstab`.

`smbtree` gives me the following:

```
$ smbtree
WORKGROUP
    \\CH7466CE              CH7466CE
        \\CH7466CE\Seagate_a1
```

Via another computer running Gnome on Ubuntu the drive is accessed from the GUI as `smb://ch7466ce/seagate_a1/`.

When I try to mount it with the above name I get:

```
$ sudo mount -t cifs -o guest,rw '\\CH7466CE\Seagate_a1' /mnt
mount error: could not resolve address for CH7466CE: Unknown error
```

Trying the same using the IP gives me:

```
$ sudo mount -t cifs -o guest,rw //192.168.0.1/Seagate_a1 /mnt
Unable to find suitable address
```

Any ideas how to get this running?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was finally solved.

There were basically 2 errors:

- IP address: I assumed that the HD would be accessible using the same IP address as the router. `nmblookup CH7466CE` told me that this is not the case:
  `192.168.0.254 CH7466CE<00>`
- Samba version: `sudo smbclient -L //192.168.0.254/seagate_a1` commented `Reconnecting with SMB1 for workgroup listing`

So i was able to mount the drive by `sudo mount -t cifs -o guest,rw,vers=1.0 //192.168.0.254/Seagate_a1 /mnt`.

The resulting `/etc/fstab` entry in order to mount the drive as "normal" user after network is up is:
`//192.168.0.254/Seagate_a1      <DIR>  cifs    guest,rw,vers=1.0,uid=1000,gid=1000,x-systemd.automount   0 0`